# Does the number of proucts in magento affect the performance of website?

Tags: performance, magento

If a website is having thousands of products.

Will it be affecting performance of website or page load time?

Comment: If you're using resource poor hosting on a configuration poor hosting provider who's lacking the technical competance and skimping on providing a Magento environment, the answer is Yes. DYH for success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No..It doesn't .. If you try to load all the products(1000), then it will be slow or cannot be load due to the memory limit. But we always load less no of products in front end at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I have to ay it does it, Recently my store slows down, and i got a call with magento support team, and they said me the problem was that i had more than 150K products.

So, yes, it is affect the store performance.

Greetings.

Comment: All software products has limits. I considered thousands of products only, not millions ...And also its depending on the server performance. If the server cannot handle large data then it will be affect loading time. If you enhance your server, then definitely you can see the performance increase of your shop..!

Comment: Ok, it depends, not only the infrastructure, my server has 64GB RAM, and stills was slowing down. I recommend install percona to increase the performance too.

Comment: Beto, I didn't meant that the performance is only depends on the higher configuration of the server. Handling the large data is always painful. But you should tune your web server. After that if you still have performance issue, then you have problem with your code, may be it should be  3rd party module or your own. You have to analyze your code. And I don't about percona that you mentioned. How it is helpful for you ..?

Answer (score 1):

I think this link may help you in your answer and what you can do to help prevent your site slowing down 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/is-magento-the-right-platform-for-1m-products